# why $\lim_{x\to+∞}\dfrac{(1+x)^{3/2}}{x^{1/2}} -x\\$

Tags: limits

\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to+∞}\frac{(1+x)^{3/2}}{x^{1/2}} -x\\[8pt]
= {} &\lim_{x\to+∞} \dfrac{(1+(1/x))^{3/2}-1}{1/x} \\[8pt]
= {} & \lim_{x\to+∞} \dfrac{\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align}
[Detailed picture with clearer specifications](https://iuimm2018.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/mmexport1574564886256.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manipulations may be:

$${(1+x)^\frac32 \over \sqrt x }-x = {(1+x)^\frac32\over x^\frac12 } - {x^\frac32\over x^\frac12}$$

$$= {x^\frac32\over x^\frac12}\left(\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^\frac32 - 1\right)$$

Using Newton’s general binomial theorem we have $\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^\frac32 = 1 + \binom{3/2}1 \frac 1x + \binom{3/2}2 \frac 1{x^2}\dots$, and since terms including higher powers of $\frac 1x$ are negligibly small ($\to 0$) we may write it as simply $1+\frac 3{2x}$.

Now, we have $$x^{\frac 32 - \frac 12}\cdot\left(1+\frac 3{2x} -1\right)$$

$$=x\cdot \frac 32\cdot \frac 1x=\boxed{\frac 32\cdot \frac 1x\over \frac 1x}$$

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: $$\nwarrow~~\uparrow~~\nearrow\\\leftarrow\text{all good}\rightarrow\\\swarrow~~\downarrow~~\searrow$$

Answer (score 0):

[Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)  has been used here $$(1+h)^n=1+\binom n1h+O(h^2)$$

Alternatively set $\dfrac1x=h$ to find $$F=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1+h)^{3/2}-1}h$$

Choose $\sqrt[3]{1+h}=u$

$$F=\lim_{u\to1}\dfrac{u^3-1}{u^2-1}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to+∞}\dfrac{(1+x)^{(\frac{3}{2})}}{x^{(1/2)}} -x\\[8pt]
& \lim_{x\to+∞}\dfrac{(1+x)^{(\frac{3}{2})}(x^{-3/2})}{x^{(1/2)}x^{-3/2}} - \frac {1}{1/x} \\[8pt]
= {} & \lim_{x\to+∞} \dfrac{(1+(1/x))^{\frac{3}{2}}-1}{1/x}
\end{align}

Apply L'Hospital Rule and you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\frac1x \to 0$ and $f(t)=(1+t)^{3/2}$ then by the definition of derivative

$$\lim_{x\to+∞} \dfrac{(1+(1/x))^{3/2}-1}{1/x}=\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{(1+t)^{3/2}-1}{t-0}=f'(0)=\frac32$$